# Rowcount in SQL not returning the correct count

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure as shown below in which I am trying to get row count based on some condition. My problem is that I get all the records no regards to conditions.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[checkForTaskTodoToday]
    @bruger VARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT daysLeft 
    FROM Todolist
    WHERE daysLeft = 0 
      AND Bruger = @bruger 
      AND udført = 0 

    RETURN @@rowcount
END
```

When I run the code from Management Studio, it returns the correct number.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you've verified the stored procedure works from SSMS, perhaps you are calling a different one in your application code.

Comment: When you say that "I run the code from Management Studio" are you saying you run the SP (which is what Dan has assumed you meant), or are you doing the same query that the SP does, inline. If it's the latter, then check the definition of the SP in the database is as you expected: maybe you changed the SP definition script but deployed it to the wrong database (e.g. master).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the @@rowcount is not working but maybe you can try the following. This will give you the count of record that you need.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[checkForTaskTodoToday]
@bruger varchar(250)
AS
begin
select Count(*) from Todolist
where daysLeft=0 and Bruger = @bruger and udført = 0 
END
```

Comment: Although this will return the row count; it won't also return the rows, like the original code does.